# ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management gives error saying it can accept only two arguments?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, parameters

I have a layer file and I need to apply unique value categories to that layer based on the field present in attribute table of that layer

I tried using:

```
input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
symbologyFields = {"VALUE_FIELD", "#", "symbol"}
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (input, output,symbologyFields)
```

But this code shows an error that ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management can accept only two arguments. But I took this code from ArcGIS tool reference site http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm

What actually I need is to color my polygons using the values in the attribute table field.

i.e.

I can say that apply symbology by going into properties tab and click on categories and the unique values and select the field. This I am in need of doing it with the help of code.

Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In addition to a more thorough code snippet, please make sure that you include the exact errors you encountered (formatted as ASCII text, so it's legible on all devices and free text searchable)

Comment: Try to changing `symbologyFields = {"VALUE_FIELD", "#", "symbol"}` to `symbologyFields = ["VALUE_FIELD", "#", "symbol"]`. There should be no curlybrackets

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for Apply Symbology From Layer with ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm#GUID-E53C37E4-D077-48F9-B0F0-B7DA5C7D158F) shows this syntax (four parameters):

```
ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (in_layer, in_symbology_layer, {symbology_fields}, {update_symbology})
```

while the [documentation for Apply Symbology From Layer with ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm#GUID-E53C37E4-D077-48F9-B0F0-B7DA5C7D158F) shows this syntax (two parameters):

```
ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (in_layer, in_symbology_layer)
```

You are working with ArcMap but referring to the documentation from ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: ok sir thank you for confirmation.
please help us to color the polygons based on the unique values in the field

Comment: That is a different question, and so should be asked as a new one, after correcting your code for the number of allowed arguments.